# Adding Virtual Machine Performance Counters

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

Looking to add performance counters to an existing Log Analytics workspace using Terraform. Since Linux counters do not appear to be natively available (Looks like Windows are), decided to try and use the azapi provider instead. Not having much luck and was wondering if anyone here has tried this before. Although the code runs (i.e. Terraform Apply completes successfully), it does nothing. It does not add the performance counter.

I have tried with both the "Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces@2020-08-01" and "Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces/dataSources@2020-08-01" types.

Another thing I have noticed, is that the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/resource-manager-workspace?tabs=json#collect-windows-performance-counters) for adding perf counters suggests there is a "kind" either of 'LinuxPerformanceObject' or 'WindowsPerformanceCounter', but I do not see where that would go into the code.

Appreciate any help.

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "3.67.0"
    }
    azapi = {
      source  = "Azure/azapi"
      version = "1.8.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "azurerm" {
  # Configuration options
  features {

  }
}
provider "azapi" {

}
```

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "this" {
  name     = "rg-eus2-law"
  location = "East US 2"
}

resource "azurerm_log_analytics_workspace" "this" {
  name                = "law-eus2"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.this.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.this.location
  sku                 = "PerGB2018"
  depends_on          = [azurerm_resource_group.this]
}

resource "azapi_update_resource" "this" {
  type        = "Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces@2020-08-01"
  resource_id = azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.this.id
  body = jsonencode({
    properties = {
      instanceName      = "*"
      intervalInSeconds = 60
      objectName        = "Memory"
      counterName       = "% Committed Bytes In Use"
    }
  })
}
```

Update. I tried this: azapi_resource

```
resource "azapi_resource" "windows_committed_bytes" {
  type      = "Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces/dataSources@2020-08-01"
  name      = "WindowsCommittedBytes"
  parent_id = azurerm_resource_group.this.id

  body = jsonencode({
    kind = "WindowsPerformanceCounter"
    properties = {
      "objectName" : "Memory",
      "instanceName" : "*",
      "intervalSeconds" : 60,
      "counterName" : "% Committed Bytes in Use"
    }
  })
}
```

**Error**: `parent_id is invalid`: expect ID of `Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces`

**FIXED!!**

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "this" {
  name     = "rg-eus2-law"
  location = "East US 2"
}

resource "azurerm_log_analytics_workspace" "this" {
  name                = "law-eus2"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.this.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.this.location
  sku                 = "PerGB2018"
  depends_on          = [azurerm_resource_group.this]
}

resource "azapi_resource" "windows_committed_bytes" {
  type      = "Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces/dataSources@2020-08-01"
  name      = "WindowsCommittedBytes"
  parent_id = azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.this.id

  body = jsonencode(
    {
      kind = "WindowsPerformanceCounter"
      properties = {
        "objectName" : "Memory",
        "instanceName" : "*",
        "intervalSeconds" : 60,
        "counterName" : "% Committed Bytes in Use"
      }
    }
  )
}

resource "azapi_resource" "windows_processor_time" {
  type      = "Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces/dataSources@2020-08-01"
  name      = "WindowsProcessorTime"
  parent_id = azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.this.id

  body = jsonencode(
    {
      kind = "WindowsPerformanceCounter"
      properties = {
        "objectName" : "Processor",
        "instanceName" : "*",
        "intervalSeconds" : 60,
        "counterName" : "% Processor Time"
      }
    }
  )
}

resource "azapi_resource" "linux_processor_time" {
  type      = "Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces/dataSources@2020-08-01"
  name      = "LinuxProcessorTime"
  parent_id = azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.this.id

  body = jsonencode(
    {
      kind = "LinuxPerformanceObject"
      properties = {
        "objectName" : "Processor",
        "instanceName" : "*",
        "intervalSeconds" : 60,
        "performanceCounters" : [
          {
            "counterName" : "% Processor Time"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  )
}

resource "azapi_resource" "linux_used_memory" {
  type      = "Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces/dataSources@2020-08-01"
  name      = "LinuxUsedMemory"
  parent_id = azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.this.id

  body = jsonencode(
    {
      kind = "LinuxPerformanceObject"
      properties = {
        "objectName" : "Memory",
        "instanceName" : "*",
        "intervalSeconds" : 60,
        "performanceCounters" : [
          {
            "counterName" : "% Used Memory"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After a few attempts, fix posted above.